# Conditional forward fill of bool values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Question:**

How do I forward fill bool `True` value in a pandas dataframe if first entry of day `== True`, to the end of a day

Please see the following example and desired output.

**Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bool_col':[True,False,False,True,False,False,False,False,False],
    'dates':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=9, freq='8h')})


   bool_col dates
0   True    2011-01-01 00:00:00
1   False   2011-01-01 08:00:00
2   False   2011-01-01 16:00:00
3   True    2011-01-02 00:00:00
4   False   2011-01-02 08:00:00
5   False   2011-01-02 16:00:00
6   False   2011-01-03 00:00:00
7   False   2011-01-03 08:00:00
8   False   2011-01-03 16:00:00
```

**Desired Output:**

```
  bool_col  dates
0   True    2011-01-01 00:00:00
1   True    2011-01-01 08:00:00
2   True    2011-01-01 16:00:00
3   True    2011-01-02 00:00:00
4   True    2011-01-02 08:00:00
5   True    2011-01-02 16:00:00
6   False   2011-01-03 00:00:00
7   False   2011-01-03 08:00:00
8   False   2011-01-03 16:00:00
```

On `2011-01-01` and `2011-01-02` we can see `True` is `ffill` until end of day but on `2011-01-03 00:00:00`  there is a `False` so no changes made.

What have I tried?

I tried using `ffill` but can't work out how to use this with the criteria I specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) is an efficient way to get a resulting series the size of the dataframe based on groupby logic. The instructions below literally translates to "group each day, and look at the first element of `bool_col`, if it's `True`, the entire group is `True` otherwise keep the group".

```
df.groupby(df.dates.dt.date).bool_col.transform(lambda g: True if g.iloc[0] else g)
Out[363]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
```

Comment: Nice solution @Boud, accepted and marked up.  I have just applied to my real data and does exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks