# Expand each "True" value in pandas DataFrame of bools to a "True-Block" of a fixed length

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe of bool values like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=range(10),
    data={
        'A': [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False],
        'B': [True, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
    }
)
```

I want to expand each `True`-value to a "`True`-Block" of at least length `n=3`, expanding it forward starting at the original `True`-value (or less than `n` if we are at the end of the DataFrame, see example A below). The desired result is in principle computed as this per column: For each `True` make sure that the next n-1 values are also `True`.  So the desired output would be

```
desired = pd.DataFrame(
    index=range(10),
    data={
        'A': [False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True],
        'B': [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False
    }
)
```

It seems to be a simple problem asking for a one-liner but I cannot get a pandas-like and efficient solution.

If found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012343/conditional-forward-fill-of-bool-values-in-pandas-dataframe), but as I am not bound by date-intervals, it does not exactly apply here.

Comment: Should the last 3 rows of desired df be all [False, False] (taking from row 6 to 8 from df)?

Comment: @Allen Sorry, I sadly do not comprehend. For `B` they should be False, but for `A` the last two rows should be `True`, as the last but 1 row is a `True` also.

Comment: Right, I think I know what you mean now. One question. why the first 7 elements are all True in column B instead of 5 or 6 which all at least 3?

Comment: @Allen, because each original `True` value should be followed by two new `True` values. So each original `True` value should start a new block, regardless of what happened before that.

Comment: It still doesn't quite make sense, from the example of column A, it seems the expanded Trues will overwrite the next rows. Can you please explain a bit more how the B column in df is transformed to desired result?

Comment: @Allen For B (iterating over original values): row 0 is True --> row 0+1=1 and 0+2=2 should be True, too. row 1 is False --> no change. Row 2 is True --> row 3 and 4 shall be True. Row 3 is True --> row 4 and 5 shall be True. row 4 is True --> 5 and 6 shall be True.  5-9 are all False, so no change.
Hence in the desired Series for B the rows 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 are True and 7,8 and 9 remain False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [97]: df.replace(False, np.nan).ffill(limit=2).fillna(False).astype(bool)
Out[97]:
       A      B
0  False   True
1  False   True
2   True   True
3   True   True
4   True   True
5  False   True
6  False   True
7  False  False
8   True  False
9   True  False
```

---

**Old answer:**

```
In [55]: idx = df.loc[df.B].index

In [57]: df.loc[idx.union(idx+1).union(idx+2), 'B'] = True

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
       A      B
0  False   True
1  False   True
2   True   True
3  False   True
4  False   True
5  False   True
6  False   True
7  False  False
8   True  False
9  False  False
```

Comment: This works for column `B` but not for column `A`. Each column is to be treated separately from each other. So I could make this to a function and apply it to each column, this would probably work, yep.

Comment: This looks great at first sight. A one-liner as I originally expected it to be :-). I will check it more carefully later today and will then give feedback.